# Traverse through JSon data in dart?

Tags: dart

After trying a lot sorry for asking such a trivial question.

Given below screenshot consist of a data that I have successfully received from the server.
[image]

I would like to know how to traverse through the data since whenever I try to cast it to something and try a foreach it gives an error.

The actual data sent from the server is a List() type.

I want to know how to cast it to same type and use it here.

I tried casting but it says unexpected token here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON.parse](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_json/JSON.html#parse) return type depends on the `String` you try to parse. See the doc :

> Parses `json` and build the corresponding parsed JSON value.
>
> Parsed JSON values are of the types `num`, `String`, `bool`, `Null`, `List`s of parsed JSON values or `Map`s from `String` to parsed JSON values.

From your screenshot, it seems that the return value is a List. You can do something like the following to use it (did you notice the typo in your commented code - `.fore`) :

```dart
final parsedList = JSON.parse(e.data)/*.fore*/;
parsedList.forEach((x){
  query('#idData').appendText(x[0]);
  query('#idData').appendText(x[1]);
  query('#idData').appendText(x[2]);
  query('#idData').appendText(x[3]);
});
```

Comment: You're so quick! Awesome :)

Comment: Ohh sorry that .fore was a mishap happened during commenting and removal of code